# Understanding Index Performance using LIKE Keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the AdventureWorks2017 database from Microsoft.

I have done the following:

```
create index idx_CarrierTrackingNumber on [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] (CarrierTrackingNumber);
go
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

select 
    CarrierTrackingNumber
from
    [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]
where
    CarrierTrackingNumber like '%4';
go
```

When I go to look at the Execution plan, it shows the following:

[image: Index Still Used despite LIKE operator]

Shouldn't a table scan be used instead of an index scan because the first character in my `LIKE` search is a wildcard?

**Edit #1: Added why I believe this**

I was reading a book, [SQL Performance explained](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3950307826) and in the book, it says:

> The opposite case is also possible: a LIKE expression that starts with
>   a wildcard. Such a LIKE expression cannot serve as an access
>   predicate. The database has to scan the entire table if there are no
>   other conditions that provide access predicates.

Did I misunderstand what the author is talking about?

Comment: Why? All the information required is within the index. No need to go near the table.

Comment: If it were `CarrierTrackingNumber like '4'` or `CarrierTrackingNumber like '4%'` then it would be an Index Seek. It can still use the Index though, via an Index Scan, to answer the query because no other columns in the table are involved.

Comment: I added some more context, see "Edit #1".

Comment: Thats a simplistic view... SQL Server will use an index or table interchangeably depending on its needs (in fact check the definition of table/index/heap - they aren't as different as you might think). Essentially what the author is saying is that a scan is required, therefore not benefiting from the sort order of the index, But in this case it can load a lot less data into memory to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Got it, Starting with a wildcharacter is a bad practice, but SQL Server will still do what it wants to do.

Comment: The wildcard still forces a scan instead of a seek... so it has to check every row... thats whats bad about it.

Comment: Got it, thank you.